# Sqitch Snowflake deployment failing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, sqitch

I am using Sqitch Snowflake Docker image **sqitch/sqitch:1.0.0-snowflake** . I can conntect to the database without any issues.
However, when I run the following

```
./sqitch deploy
```

It just stays at the following forever.

```
Adding registry tables to test_db
```

I have checked the logs at snowflake side in **information_schema.query_history()** table and it is failing at the following

```
USE SCHEMA sqitch
SQL compilation error:
Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.
```

It seems that even when pointed to an empty database, Sqitch is assuming that the SQITCH schema already exists.

private_key_path = "/home/bcg/rsa_key_poc.p8" seems to be the issue in ~/.snowsql/config
I can `docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash` and deploy it within the container successfully. But it doesn't work from the host machine. I am using CentOS 7.7

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by adding **SNOWSQL_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE** variable to the [docker-sqitch](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch/blob/master/docker-sqitch.sh) script (under Iterate over optional Sqitch and engine variables)